# Send list of objects to another form

Tags: c#, .net, list, listbox, addition

I have list of objects of one class in form1. In form2 I have list box which is needed to be populated with object from list from form1. Here is small code

```
public class Form1:Form
{
   public List<RegistrationInformation> car = new List<RegistrationInformation>();

   private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //Create new object of class Registrationinformation which have created
      //new property like a Name, Surname, Car...

      RegistrationInformation c = new RegistrationInformation();
      c.Name= txtName.Text;
      c.Surname= txtSurname.Text;
      c.Car= txtCar.Text;
      car.Add(c); //Add object to list
      int number = car.Count; //this give me right result every next time
    }
}

public class Form2:Form
{
    //I tried this
    Form 1 frm = new Form1();
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(frm.car);

    //In this form I have some information about registered car and his owner
    //The left side of form is for listBox the right side is for some controls           
    //like is label, text box..When I select one item from list box I want to show information about them
    //So for that I tried with next code 

    int number = frm.car.Count; //But I find this problem - this give me result 0
    //So this code don't work
    if (number > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
           string NameSurname = frm.car[i].Name + " " + rg.car[i].Surname;
           listBox1.Items.Add(NameSurname);
        }
    }
}
```

I have problem with adding item to listbox from list of object. When I call list in form 2 I get result that they don't have item. I adding item on button click. So every time when user change txtBox Name/Surname/Car and click on Button1 they CREATE one object of class with property methods Name,Surname,Car. Then object is putting to List. On second button I open form 2 and I have screen like I describe in comment after - listBox1.Items.AddRange(frm.car);

Do you maybe know what is a problem why second form don't see item's in list?

**Update:** I forgot to add that i create new instance of Form1 and access with it to car list when form load i tried to add that i constructor of class form2 but without success.

Comment: You can do this in many different ways: Using constructor,
using objects,
using properties,
using delegates.. Here is a nice article about that--> [passing data between forms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the list in your first form:

```
public List<RegistrationInformation> car = new List<RegistrationInformation>();
```

You add items to that list when a button is clicked in `btnRegister_Click`.

In `Form2` you create an instance of `Form1` and call it `frm` and access the `car` list. This new form `frm`, no one has clicked the button, so the list `car` is empty. Therefore, you are getting no items in the list.

Comment: I forgot to add that i create new instance of Form1 and access with it to car list when form load i tried to add that i constructor of class form2 but without success

Comment: Sorry are you asking me something? What do you want to achieve and i will see if I can help you?

Comment: I tried to add that(creating instance of form1 and call it with car list) peace of code to button but it don't work. Do you have some other solution

Comment: Where is the button2 which opens the 2nd form?

Comment: But the code which adds items to car is in a button click. I am still not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah - I add item to list with button click. The list is in Form1. When i click on button on form2 to call item from list to put them in listbox i don't get answer because second form don't see that list have items.

Comment: Menu item open second form. On second form i have button which create instance of form1, call list car and add there items to listbox but listbox is again empty.

Comment: I think i know what you are trying. One more question: why do you create instance of form1when button is pressed on 2nd form?

Comment: Because list is in form1 so if i want to call someone item from list in form2 i need instance(object of form1) to access to list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132044/discussion-between-codingyoshi-and-mionis).

Comment: Thank you very much :) PS: Answer is in chat

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the scope of the variable.  Like @CodingYoshi wrote, the instance of `Form1` you have created in `Form2` never had any car added to the list.

I would suggest that you create a new class to host the list in question (possibly as a singleton, or instantiated by the "main" form).  This way, you would be able to share the list between `Form1` and `Form2`.

Comment: I forgot to add that i create new instance of Form1 and access with it to car list when form load i tried to add that i constructor of class form2 but without success